# EAActionSheetPicker - get row in delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im new to iOS. I am using an EAActionSheetPicker (https://github.com/EckyZero/EAActionSheetPickerDemo).

I initiate my picker like this:

```
- (void)initLocationPicker
{
NSMutableArray* names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_data.count];
for(Model *item in _data)
    [names addObject:item.name];

self.locationPicker = [[EAActionSheetPicker alloc]initWithOptions:names];
self.locationPicker.delegate = self;
}
```

What i want to achieve is that when i press the done-button; I want to know which index was selected in the picker. I get the actual label by implementing the delegate method as this:

```
-(void)EAActionSheetPicker:(EAActionSheetPicker *)actionSheet
didDismissWithSelection:(id)selection
           inTextField:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"selected: %@", selection);
}
```

How can I know which index that was?

Might perhaps be obvious.

Thanks

Edit:

Perhaps the best solution is to initiate the EAActionSheetPicker with my actual dataarray. Don't know if it's worth the trouble though.

Comment: What does the (id)selection return? try logging the selection in this method

Comment: Yea, sorry. My pasted code here was wrong. I edited the question now. The selection is the actual NSString that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

In **EAActionSheetPicker.m** 
in this method 
    `- (void)hide:(UISegmentedControl *)sender` put

**self.textField.tag=row;**

after this line `NSInteger row = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];`

now in your delegate method

```
-(void)EAActionSheetPicker:(EAActionSheetPicker *)actionSheet
didDismissWithSelection:(id)selection
           inTextField:(UITextField *)textField{

NSLog(@"index: %@", textField.tag);

yourLabel.text=[names objectAtIndex:textField.tag];
}
```

//UITextField Delegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   self.picker.textField = textField;
  [self.picker showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: the thing is that the textfield is nil, since I'm not using a textField to represent the picked data; but a textLabel.